# Add an underscore before the last digit followed by any number in a string

Tags: r, regex

This must be easy, but I can't handle it. Sorry for that!

**I have** this string:

```
string <- c("AB1C1", "AB2C2", "AB3C20")
[1] "AB1C1"  "AB2C2"  "AB3C20"
```

I would like to **ADD** an underscore before the last character followed by any digit.

**Desired output:**

```
[1] "AB1_C1"  "AB2_C2"  "AB3_C20"
```

**I have tried so far:**

I can match with regex: `[A-Z][0-9]+$` the last character followed by any digit.

But I don't know how to **ADD** an underscore before this match

Comment: Have you considered using different method as regexex? As far as I know, they are not made for changing strings.

Comment: @PeterTrencansky changing strings is certainly something regex is intended to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
sub("(.*)(\\D\\d+)$", "\\1_\\2", string)
## => [1] "AB1_C1"  "AB2_C2"  "AB3_C20"
sub("(\\D\\d+)$", "_\\1", string)
## => [1] "AB1_C1"  "AB2_C2"  "AB3_C20"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HCBshZ/1%5D) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/HCBshZ/2). *Details*:

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `(\D\d+)` - Group 2: any non-digit and then one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/ll5cim):

```r
string <- c("AB1C1", "AB2C2", "AB3C20")
sub("(.*)(\\D\\d+)$", "\\1_\\2", string)
## => [1] "AB1_C1"  "AB2_C2"  "AB3_C20"
```